# Visual Studio 2015 & TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015

Good evening.

I have been trying to connect to TFS 2010 source through Visual Studio 2015. I am able to view TFS 2010 server and projects from VS 2015.However, IDE throws 'object reference not set to an instance of an object' exception when I try to connect to any of projects in TFS server. Much appreciate any further advise.

[image]

Comment: That is supposed to work, but just to be sure, which exact version is that TFS 2010 server on? 2010 rtm? SP1, SP1+Forwardcompat? Check: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/03/23/keeping-your-tfs-2010-up-to-date-as-of-march-2012.aspx

Comment: Which exact version of VS are you using? 2015, 2015u1?

Comment: Check whether the Activitylog contains any clues: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx

Comment: @jessehouwing, Thanks. We have SQL Server 2008R2, Windows server 2008 R2 -standard (62 bit) and TFS 2010 version - 10.0.40219.1 (SP1 KB2182621) on the source control server; and VS 2015 ultimate.

Comment: If you can connect TFS through  Web access，it may has problem in your VS. Try to run command devenv.exe /resetsettings  to restore Visual Studio default settings  or reinstall TeamExploer2015 in VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We couldn't get this working in TFS 2010 and hence migrated to TFS 2015 solved this issue.