# does visual studio express 2015 support TFS 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-express

**[Update]**
*I understand I can use 2015 side by side with VS 2010, but we've had problems just polluting our environment. If there is a chance someone has done this, it could save me a lot of time and energy instead of going with an install only to find out it doesn't work. It's also unfortunate this isn't documented anywhere.*

---

So just like the title says.

To give some more background we're hoping to use VS2015 with our testers to kick start using selenium, but our task/bug management is all on TFS2010.

I don't want to distort the testers' environment, neither can I play with any of our dev machines to try this out physically. A VM will just not really run on our, *not so fast* machines.

My google-fu didn't get me to far. The VS2015 Express features [does mention TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs), but I want to know specifically if it supports **TFS 2010**. Additionally I found a [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/tfs/administer/requirements). This talks about the various VS and TFS versions but nothing here about VS **Express**

Related SO posts I found:

- [Visual Studio 2015 & TFS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33528986/visual-studio-2015-tfs-2010) <sub>Not specific about VS **express** or not, no definitive answer</sub>
- [Visual Studio 2015 with TFS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35789081/visual-studio-2015-with-tfs-2010) <sub>More unrelated, this is about builds going wrong</sub>

Comment: It's worth noting that TFS2010 is end-of-life. Support ended in July of last year. You should really upgrade to a more modern version of TFS.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run VS2010 and VS2015 side-by-side, but not on the same solution/project files.

Once you open an older project in 2015, a project conversion will happen. If I recall correctly, project compatibiliy started to stabilizer around VS2012, but don't quote me on that, I'd say it is not likely.

You will NOT be able to open the same project in both at the same time afaik, so it's a one-time shift that'd meet your needs.

As far as task tracking systems go, you could also opt in on [VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs) and do a one-time export of your existing bugs/tasks. Shouldn't take you more than a day or so to plan and migrate those over.

Comment: Again, it not so much about running side by side stuff. We just want a tightly controlled environment within minimal pollutants. I was just wondering if any devs out there have tried or done this and they could give me a definitive answer before I go spend hours trying to install this stuff and then have to uninstall if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the project with VS2015 but it will be upgraded to a newer state. We recently done this and could not go back using VS2010. Otherwise you can version control and keep both projects, i.e. the old implementation and the upgraded one. You could try with VS2015 Community Edition.

Comment: Yes, but like I said, I would like to avoid trying. Also, this isn't about opening an old project in a new one. Just a definitive answer about TFS 2010 support in VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

You sure can run both versions side by side, but not on the same project.  Also, the Microsoft Test Manager that comes with Visal Studio 2015 will not connect to TFS 2010.  It tells you that it needs an older version of MTM.  I am still working out the kinks on our systems.